# Notification on browser download finished

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, webclient

I am designing an application where I am stumble across one requirement.

My application is firing download by using following syntax.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://openintents.googlecode.com/files/FileManager-2.0.2.apk"));

startActivity(intent);
```

above code opens browser page which in turn starts download.

My requirement is I need to get notified once that download is complete.

Since there are no broadcast available which will notify me when browser completes download, I have used somewhat hacky approach.

I am using `RecursiveFileObserver` to monitor SD Card contents with `FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE` flag.

My plan is once this event is called I will compare the path contents with downloaded file name and will trigger next action.

But the issue I am facing is FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE is called multiple times and it varies device to device.

**My question is, is there any API or workaround available which will notify me once browser completes download?**

Below is code snippet that I have tried.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://openintents.googlecode.com/files/FileManager-2.0.2.apk"));

startActivity(intent);

myObserver = new RecursiveFileObserver(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {

        if (event == FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE) {

            if (path.indexOf("FileManager") != -1) {
                Log.i("vipul", "CLOSE_WRITE: " + path);

                /*
                 * Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 * intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)),
                 * "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                 * startActivity(intent);
                 */

            }

        }
    }

};

myObserver.startWatching();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    if (installReceiver != null) {
        myObserver.stopWatching();
        unregisterReceiver(installReceiver);
        installReceiver = null;

    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the download using your own service and tracking the progress by fetching the file size before you start using getContentLength() and tracking the downloaded part size.

Comment: I have to do it through browser.Thats the client requirment.